# Python Gauss Elimination

Tags: python, gauss

Super New to programming and still learning how to debug. Every time I run this program for Gauss elimination I get

> "line 16, in GaussElim
>       tmp=A[maxRow][k]
>   IndexError: list index out of range"

I think it mean the code is stepping over the limit of the index, but I am not sure on how to correct it. Any advice would be much appreciated thank you!

```
def GaussElim(A):
n=len(A)

for i in range(0,n):   #search for maximum in this column
    maxE1=abs(A[i][i])
    maxRow=i
    for k in range(i+1,n):
        if abs(A[k][i])>maxE1:
            maxE1=abs(A[k][i])
            maxRow=k
            # swap maximum row with current row (column by column)
    for k in range(i,n+1):
        tmp=A[maxRow][k]
        A[maxRow][k]=A[i][k]
        A[i][k]=tmp

    for k in range(i+1,n):
        c=-A[k][i]/A[i][i]
        for j in range(i,n+1):
            if i==j:
                A[k][j]=0
            else:
                A[k][j]+=c*A[i][j]
                #solve equation Ax+b for an upper triangular matrix A
x=[0 for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n-1,-1,-1):
    x[i]=A[i][n]/A[i][i]
    for k in range(i-1,-1,-1):
        A[k][n]-=A[k][i]*x[i]
return x

def main():
A=[[2,7,3,6,2],
        [3,3,4,4,6],
        [6,9,5,3,3],
        [6,9,5,3,3],
        [4,2,1,7,5]]

mysum1 = GaussElim(A)
print('a) GaussElimination Solution = {:.1f}'.format(mysum1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, lists are zero indexed. If you print the value of k, you'll see you're getting a value k=5, which is presumably coming from your range(i, n+1) (where n=5). Your 5x5 array will only support indexing from 0 to 4.

Comment: so how would you take the +1 off? how I keep it from going to 5?

Comment: I don't know anything about how that will affect the correctness of the algorithm but that should prevent that particular IndexError. `range(i, n+1)` gives you `[i, i+1, ..., n]`, and `range(i, n)` will give you `[i, i+1, ..., n-1]`. (or [] if i=n)